# How should I handle text IO in custom command line?

Tags: c++, io, cmd, sdl

I am currently making a text based game, but have been told to stay as far away from windows cmd as I can, so I am making my own command line in SDL.

I can get text to display just find but I run into a few issues. Currently I store the console's text in a large array e.g. 'consoleText[1600]' this works fine except for when I render. When I render I loop through the entire array and it crawls to a halt. Obviously it cannot loop through that large array each frame but I am having trouble deciding how I should go about handling this (I assume that one large array is a poor choice).

What would be a appropriate way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: SDL is a graphic library right ? If not, I consider you made an error in your question tags

Comment: why have you been told to stay away from windows command line?

Comment: Windows Command line is not typically considered suitable due to the fact that it is windows only and you have to jump through a lot more hoops to make special things work with it. This is just off of things I have read and heard in the past.

Comment: Jump through what kinds of hoops? To make what 'special' things work? Are you trying to use the console window to draw game sprites? Are you trying to make the console window display 64k colors?

Comment: I believe as far as getting keys without printing and any sort of graphical enhancements (not too important for most any tbg) and then no I am trying to avoid one standard OS

Comment: If you want to make a console application why not use a console library like curses. If you want to make a graphical application using SDL then make a graphical application.

Comment: I am using a hybrid for this particular project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on "Currently I store the console's text in a large array" I'm assuming you're using SDL to emulate the "archaic" character mode of "ancient times" where characters could be randomly written to screen by placing them in the correct offset from 0xBC00 for CGA or 0xB000 for MDA (arg I feel old now).

Two suggestions:

1. Show some code. I can't believe even rendering 1600 characters one at a time would cause SDL to crawl. You're probably doing something wrong, not double buffering correctly, or some such.
2. Rendering a single large string would still be faster. So store your buffer as a single string with line breaks and put it in the screen at once. Need colors use 16 buffers. 16 large strings render faster than 1600 small ones.

Comment: I use a loop as such- for(int i=0; i<1600; i++){draw[i]} and come render time, I run that loop to display each and every character... but it is ungodly slow.

Comment: I do believe that the issue is not in rendering them (exactly) but looping through the 1600 large array on each frame..

Comment: What does draw() do? Are you using SDL_ttf, SDL_FreeType? Do you draw to a surface and then apply it to the screen once or every time?

Comment: I did look into it (sorry I am a SDL newbie) and I am drawing to a surface and applying it every iteration. This is most likely the cause of my lag and I am rewriting it now. (also yes your post was dead on with what I am trying to do, assuming this works I shall accept it.)